# After migrating Grails 2.4.4 to 3.0.1, compiling failed

Tags: grails

For upgrading my website from Grails 2.4.4 to Grails 3.0.1

I use Grails 3.0.1 to create a new app
( grails create-app mywebsite2 --profile=web )

and I simply copied controller, domains and src ( include groovy and java source code ) from old app (mywebsite) to new app

when I ran 'compile' command in grails console, it issued ‘:compileJava FAILED’

then, I figured out that Grails 3.0.x compiles Java and Groovy separately.
( :compileJava and :compileGroovy )
because I have some Java code use Groovy domain classes, so it compiles failed.

but it's OK with Grails 2.4.4

how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you copy the code to `src/main/groovy` and `src/main/java`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yes, I've copied src/main/groovy/* and src/main/java/*

Comment: One way to make this work is to put your Java source files under `src/main/groovy/`.  They can still be left as Java source files.

Comment: Something like https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/e212ff039970b3a9b798 would probably work too.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thanks for you reply, I didn't find `sourceSets`, so I simply copied `src/main/java` to `src/main/groovy` and ran `compile`, there's another issue:`/src/main/groovy/backend/tools/BoundBox.java:80: ??: ????: \188
   s = coordinatesArray[i].replace('，', ',');
                                     ^`   so weired that console shows error in `?`

Comment: You won't find `sourceSets` unless you add it.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I added `sourceSets` to `build.gradle`, got `/src/main/java/com/tourting/website/backend/tools/ExportBeautySpot.java:132: ??: ?????
   statement.setString(2, beautySpot.getCity().getForeignName());`  the `beautySpot` come from `BeautySpot` in `domain` directory, I suspect srcDir ordering issue, I set `srcDir` as `"grails-app/conf",
"grails-app/domain",
"grails-app/controllers",
"grails-app/services",
"grails-app/taglib",
"grails-app/util",
"src/main/java",
"src/main/groovy"`, didn't work neither :(

Comment: I guess the only way I can do is rewrite java code into groovy code :(